# Function with derived type parameter in a dictionary with the Type as the Key

Tags: c#

I want to be able to store a function in a dictionary with the Key being the object type.  All functions will accept objects derived from the same base class.  I want to be able to convert (based on a registered function) a class into a DbCommand. I've listed my code below in the form that seems correct but something is wrong with the syntax, etc.  I think I'm missing something really simple... Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
private Dictionary<object, Func<TrackingRecord, DbCommand>> conversionFunctions = new Dictionary<object, Func<TrackingRecord, DbCommand>>();


public void RegisterConversionFunction<T>(Func<T, DbCommand> conversionFunction) where T : TrackingRecord
    {
        conversionFunctions.Add(typeof(T), conversionFunction);
    }

public DbCommand GetConverstion<T>(T trackingRecord) where T : TrackingRecord
    {
        DbCommand command = null;

        if (conversionFunctions.ContainsKey(trackingRecord.GetType()))
        {
            Func<T, DbCommand> conversionFunction;
            if (conversionFunctions.TryGetValue(trackingRecord.GetType(), out conversionFunction))
            {
                command = conversionFunction.Invoke(trackingRecord);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            command = DefaultConversion(trackingRecord);
        }
        return command;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of C#/.net is this?

Comment: TrackingRecord is a custom class

Comment: The Dictionary won't accept the Function because the input parameter is different.  I've been able to solve it by changing the input parameter type of the function to object...but I think that's a bit sloppy.

Comment: @GertArnold: Thanks - Argument type 'System.Func<T,System.Data.Common.DbCommand>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Func<TrackingRecord, System.Data.Common.DbCommand>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your original solution is that the method signature `Func<T, DbCommand>` doesn't match the expected value `Func<TrackingRecord, DbCommand>`.  To fix this, because you know that T is constrained to inherit from TrackingRecord, you can create a wrapping function that matches the expected signature (`Func<TrackingRecord, DbCommand>`) and cast the argument to T.

Try this:

```
private Dictionary<object, Func<TrackingRecord, DbCommand>> conversionFunctions = new Dictionary<object, Func<TrackingRecord, DbCommand>>();

public void RegisterConversionFunction<T>(Func<T, DbCommand> conversionFunction) where T : TrackingRecord
{
    conversionFunctions.Add(typeof(T), tr => conversionFunction((T)tr));
}

public DbCommand GetConverstion<T>(T trackingRecord) where T : TrackingRecord
{
    DbCommand command = null;
    Func<TrackingRecord, DbCommand> conversionFunction;

    if (conversionFunctions.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out conversionFunction))
        command = conversionFunction.Invoke(trackingRecord);
    else
        command = DefaultConversion(trackingRecord);

    return command;
}
```

Comment: I cleaned this up a bit so that it only checks the dictionary once, and does so using T (so that subclasses of T fail to resolve, as they should) and also uses a strong cast rather than an "as" cast so that errors are more apparent.